# How to Load Icomoon Font

Tags: css, fonts, sass, icons, font-face

I am trying to figure out how to incorporate [Icomoon](http://icomoon.io) fonts into my site, but I can't get the font to load. I downloaded the files and coped them to my /fonts directory. Then I followed the instructions [here](http://chipcullen.com/how-to-use-icomoon-and-icon-fonts-part-1-basic-usage/) and copied the files in icomoon/fonts to /fonts. I edited icomoon/style.css to read:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And I included this in my style.scss "@import "../fonts/icomoon/style.css";". On one of my [pages](http://oakwood.slamagency.com/sample-post-3/), I tried to include an icon, but it doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools > Network Tab > Search "icomoon" produces 0 results. Are you sure you're compiling your .scss file properly?

Comment: I put this "@import "../fonts/icomoon/style.css";" in my style.scss, but when I compile, my style.css reads "@import url(../fonts/icomoon/style.css);" (it's missing quotes inside the parentheses). Maybe that's the problem? Why would it be compiling wrong?

Comment: Okay, so I changed style.scss to read "@import url("../fonts/icomoon/style.css");" which outputs "@import url("../fonts/icomoon/style.css");" in style.css, but the icons still aren't working. Thoughts?

Comment: SASS imports are marked up a bit differently. When you're compiling your .scss file, it's just seeing that line as a line of CSS (which it is). Regardless, I'd recommend just copy/pasting the code in your OP into your main stylesheet.

Comment: SASS imports work like this: `@import 'reset';` will import `_reset.scss`. See: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: The simplest way I will show you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998838/how-to-use-easily-icomoon-icon-to-website-change-colour-of-icon-and-adding-more/55999027#55999027

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured it out. I changed my icomoon/style.css to read:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('../icomoon.eot');
src:url('../icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
url('../icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../icomoon.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And I changed the call in style.scss to "@import url("../fonts/icomoon/style.css");". Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that you called that font in your main css *style.css* (http://oakwood.slamagency.com/wp-content/themes/reverie-oakwood/css/style.css)
And also I cant see that u called *icomoon/style.css* anywhere in header.
Try to call file *icomoon/style.css* or add needed code to main theme css *style.css*

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment as it's a suggestion/observation and not a complete solution.

Comment: I know that, but comments on main question cant be made if user doesn't have 50 reputation. So better help like this than not helping at all, right? :)

Comment: Ah, good point. Edit your answer so I can remove my downvote, otherwise it's locked in by SO :)