# How to use Icomoon icon to website, change Colour of Icon and Adding more icon in future?

Tags: html, css

I am using **Icomoon** on my **Website** and **Project**. And I am **troubled to add an Icomooon** icon to my website. 
So if any easy way to use an Icomoon icon to the website, after add it will removed of we can add more icon to the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am researching on icomoon and I luckily find out the most reliable way to use icomoon to website.

**Step 1:** Select Icon to add your Website
**Step 2:** Click on *Generate SVG & More*

[image: Step 1 & step 2 Image]
**Step 3:** Click on *Get Code*
[image: Step 3 Image]
**Step 4:** *Copy HTML* and paste to in your code where you want to use.
**Step 5:** *Copy Symbol Defination* and paste between below code:

```
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
//Paste Symbol Defination code Here
</defs>
</svg>
```

**Step 6:** Copy CSS for styling your Icon and changing the color, size and many more of Icomoon.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
  color:red;
}

.iconBook {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
  color:Green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>IcoMoon Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<!–– At Her You can add Icon Defination  ––>
<symbol id="icon-books" viewBox="0 0 18 16">
<title>books</title>
<path d="M3.5 2h-3c-0.275 0-0.5 0.225-0.5 0.5v11c0 0.275 0.225 0.5 0.5 0.5h3c0.275 0 0.5-0.225 0.5-0.5v-11c0-0.275-0.225-0.5-0.5-0.5zM3 5h-2v-1h2v1z"></path>
<path d="M8.5 2h-3c-0.275 0-0.5 0.225-0.5 0.5v11c0 0.275 0.225 0.5 0.5 0.5h3c0.275 0 0.5-0.225 0.5-0.5v-11c0-0.275-0.225-0.5-0.5-0.5zM8 5h-2v-1h2v1z"></path>
<path d="M11.954 2.773l-2.679 1.35c-0.246 0.124-0.345 0.426-0.222 0.671l4.5 8.93c0.124 0.246 0.426 0.345 0.671 0.222l2.679-1.35c0.246-0.124 0.345-0.426 0.222-0.671l-4.5-8.93c-0.124-0.246-0.426-0.345-0.671-0.222z"></path>
</symbol>

<symbol id="icon-davidstar" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<title>davidstar</title>
<path d="M16 6.96l1.873 3.040h-3.745l1.872-3.040zM24.799 21.264h-3.725l1.853-3.018 1.872 3.018zM7.202 21.264l1.872-3.018 1.853 3.018h-3.725zM11.994 23l4.006 6.5 4.007-6.5h7.993l-4.006-6.49 4.006-6.51h-7.993l-4.007-6.5-4.006 6.5h-7.994l4.007 6.51-4.007 6.49h7.994zM24.799 11.736l-1.872 3.035-1.853-3.035h3.725zM16 26.039l-1.872-3.039h3.745l-1.873 3.039zM10.141 16.51l2.92-4.774h5.879l2.921 4.774-2.939 4.754h-5.86l-2.921-4.754zM7.202 11.736h3.725l-1.853 3.035-1.872-3.035z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>



    <b>1. Book: 
   <svg class="iconBook icon-books"><use xlink:href="#icon-books"></use></svg>
   </b>

<br />

    <b>2. Star:  
    <svg class="icon icon-davidstar"><use xlink:href="#icon-davidstar"></use></svg>
    <b>
    <br/><br>
<b>You can use more icon in future. easily by adding Html, Icon defination and CSS</b>
</body>
</html>
```